# Serialize form to a specific json format

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use .serializeArray(), my data looks like:

```
[ Object { Name="Name", Value="MyName" }, Object { Name="Age", Value="15"} ]
```

But I want it to look like:

```
{ Name: "MyName", Age: 15 }
```

What do I need to do?

My form:

```
<form id="newUser">
<input id="Name" name="Name" />
<input id="Age" name="Age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be in that format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize form to JSON with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery)

Comment: backbone.js requires it to be like tha.

Comment: That solved my problem, can you delete this question please?

Comment: You should be able to delete or close the question yourself. There *should* be some controls for that below the post (near `link | edit` etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a bit of code which takes the first format and then converts it into the other. Just have it loop over the array and take Name as a key in the object, and Value as the value for the key and assign each pair into a single object.